# Local SQL Server database to cloud database C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, cloud

I have an application desktop: Windows Forms C#. I want work with a local database then at the end of the day, copy the local data to a cloud database. And I want to do it automatically.

Does such a technology exist, to do this? Or what would you advise me to do?

Thanks,

Comment: only data or also the schema?

Answer (score 0):

Right click the database itself, Tasks -> Generate Scripts...

Then follow the wizard.

In SQL Server Management Studio, if you want to also export the data, on the "Set Scripting Options" step, select the "Advanced" button and change "Schema Only" to "Data Only" or "Schema and Data".